# Library for lossless image conversion

Tags: c#, image-processing

Is there any c# library that handles lossless conversion between different image formats?

Comment: Any particular image formats?

Comment: How can you have a lossless conversion to a lossy format?  i.e. there's no such thing as a lossless conversion between GIF and JPEG.  Are you only interested in the scope of lossless image formats?

Comment: Not all formats are lossless, I think you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: I'm building a lightweight image store thingy and is interested in commonly used formats on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such thing as a universally lossless conversion routine.

Some image formats (ie: GIF and JPEG [not 2k]) are inherently lossy.  If you convert to those formats, you will always lose information.

If you are converting between lossless formats (ie: bmp, png, etc), ANY image library, including the FCL Image/Bitmap classes, will work perfectly fine.

Comment: How is GIF lossy (except for a 256-color maximum)?

Comment: It's lossy in color depth.  You lose info in the color palette.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of librarys I can use?

Comment: The framework libraries work well.  There's even an article on MSDN showing how to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/twss4wb0.aspx